# Get ASPNET Core Razor Page name in _Layout file to update navigation items

Tags: navigation, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

Using Bootstrap 4 and need to add the active class to navigation items to reflect current Razor page (new razor pages in Core 2.0).  How can I find out which page/controller I am on so I can add the active class name to the proper:

`<li><a class="active">...`

Thanks.

**Update:**
I was able to solve this with the following code in my page initializer:

```
@{
    var _action = this.Url.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName;
    var NavDashboard = "/abc";
    ...
}
```

Then I can add the "active" class in each nav items like:

```
<a asp-page="@NavDashboard" class="nav-link@(_action=="@NavDashboard" ? " active" : string.Empty)">Dashboard</a>
```

Rinse and repeat for each nav item.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get the page while you are in the layout file?

Comment: Updated the original post with solution.

Answer (score 10):

I'd go with a [custom tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring) to add the active class to an element.

I forked [Ben Cull's ActiveRouteTagHelper for MVC](http://benjii.me/2017/01/is-active-route-tag-helper-asp-net-mvc-core/) and modified it for Razor Pages and called it [ActivePageTagHelper](https://gist.github.com/DanElliott/32787b4ae1941780d70cb085d55f8b24). It's used similarly to his, like this:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li is-active-page asp-page="/Index"><a asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
        <li is-active-page asp-page="/About"><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
        <li is-active-page asp-page="/Contact"><a asp-page="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Don't forget to register your own project as a TagHelper project in your _ViewImports.cshtml as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#managing-tag-helper-scope